# App crashes after showing memory warning in ios 5.1.1 only while taking image from camera

Tags: iphone, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi I have gone through many question on SO [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689119/ios-5-gm-error-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register) but its not helping me for ios 5.1.1.When i take image for first 2 times its working fine then n3rd time the app shows memory warning and gets crashed.Here is my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    if (image) {

    if ([appdel.arrImageData count]==0) {
        count=0;

    }
    count++;
    [appdel.arrImageData addObject:[image copy]];
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you take a picture, you keep a copy of it in arrImageData and so filling up memory until iOS kills you app since you take too much memory. Re-think your design so you keep only one image in memory. If you need all the pictures for what ever reason, save it in the documents or cache directory and clean memory before taking another picture.

Comment: no i cant do that because i have to show my added images in a scrollview in that same page

Comment: Ok, can't you show thumbs of the images which use considerable less memory. Right now you have several high res images in memory and you probably don't need high res for your scrollview

Comment: but thumbs are created for video i guess.Is it possible to create for images?

Comment: You have to do it your self, have a look at http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/10/01/scaling-images-and-creating-thumbnails-from-uiviews/ I have it done it myself, but it seems to be 4 lines of code ;)

Comment: if you write your images as a jpeg to the disk, and then create a new image by reading those jpeg images, UIImage will automatically delete the images from RAM and read them off the disk again, whenever necessary to avoid crashing your app.

Answer (score 2):

i Corrected your code check it it will help or not

```
  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        if (image) {

        if ([appdel.arrImageData count]==0) {
            count=0;

        }
        count++;
        [appdel.arrImageData addObject:[image copy]];
    }

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[picker release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the memory management of your ImagePickerController. But I had a problem with deallocating my picker just after I called dismissModal...

Try to dismiss modal view and picker after you get the image.

UPDATE:
I agree with you. I had too many issues related to trying to make pickerController work for many iOS versions on several devices starting from iOS 3 to 5. As result I've skipped supporting of iOS 3 and started implementing own code to work with pictures and movies based on [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188), [AV Foundation Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

An app quite often receives memory warning when it is using `UIImagePickerController`. What happens is when you take the image and take the image again and again your memory keeps on increasing every time (If you are not managing memory correctly.In my case it used to increase every 1.5MB). So it might work for the first,second or third time and receive memory warning the very next time or it could receive memory warning on the very first time if there are too many apps running in the background.

What is important is here how you to handle this memory warning. Once an app receives a memory warning the `viewDidUnload` of all the active view controllers is called where you should release all unwanted objects which can be created again. So your app might be crashing because you are doing something wrong there..  So in short we will need to see both your .h and .m files..

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972454/compressing-image-taken-from-device-or-chosen-from-library-ios/9972544#9972544) you can get what you want.

in that code i have simply put autorelease pool to release memory.

i hope this may help you.